# how to print out the duplicate numbers in each block: block1, block2 ...?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

how to print out the duplicate numbers in each block: block1, block2 ...?

```
block1
11
12
12
13
block2
11
13
13
11
11
```

Desired Output:

```
block1 12 2
block2 13 2
block2 11 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'function prnt() { for (i in seen) if (seen[i] > 1) print b, i, seen[i] }
/^[0-9]+$/ {seen[$1]++; next}
{prnt(); b=$1; delete seen}
END{prnt()}' file
```

```
block1 12 2
block2 11 3
block2 13 2
```

`/^[0-9]+$/` condition checks if value in `$0` is numeric or not.

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne 'sub output { $seen{$_} > 1 and print "$block $_ $seen{$_}" for keys %seen }
           if (/block/) { output(); %seen = (); $block = $_ }
           else { ++$seen{$_} }
           END { output() }'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- the `%seen` hash is used to count the occurrences for each block, `$block` stores the name of the current block
- output has been moved to a subroutine as you need to call it twice: once for each new block, and once at the very end